# Edittext text change and action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have textview I want to add search button to action bar if there's any text in this textview

any idea how to achieve that , I added the listener as following

```
private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

              public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
              }

              public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
              }

              public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                      int count) {

                  invalidateOptionsMenu();

              }
            };
            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

                if(seachEditText.getText().toString().length() > 0){
                     // add the search button to action bar
                }
                else{
                    // remove the search button to action bar
                }

                return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
            }
```

How to dynamically add remove search button to the action bar